# Database design for log data evaluation

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database

I have been tasked with developing a tool for evaluating log files and I am looking for a suitable database design. There are several dozen applications producing log files in CSV format, but every application has different columns and data types. At startup every application would be sending its current log file to the server, that inserts new rows into a SQL Server database.

So far I came up with the following designs. From what I've read in other posts, it is strongly discouraged using EAV design and it doesn't convince me either having to store all data as string. So the only alternative I came up with, is to have one table per application.

Are there any other options I haven't considered yet? In case you've been in a similar situation, which design did you choose?

1.) One table per application

```
ApplicationA(A, B, C, D, E)
ApplicationB(B, E, H, J)
ApplicationC(C, P, N, X, Y)
```

Pros:

- Simple design

Cons:

- Lots of tables
- Whenever a new project is introduced a corresponding table has to be created
- In case file format changes, table definition has to be changed

2.) EAV-model

```
Applications(AppId, Name)
DataTypes(DTypeId, Name)
Properties(PropId, Name, DTypeId)
ApplicationProperties(AppId, PropId)
Values(ValueId, AppId, PropId, Value)
```

Pros:

- No need for adding new tables or columns

Cons:

- All values are stored as string
- SQL queries are more complicated due to lots of joins and casts

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, sexier is not always better.  The simple 1 table per application design gets my vote for simplicity. The maintenance of adding tables shouldn't be a big deal. No other designs came to mind.

However, you will need a different query to get the data for each application. So if you're talking about a high number of applications, it will save you a lot of time developing the application to GET the data back if you go with the EAV design since you will probably be able to create one function that will retrieve log info for any application just by sending a different parameter.

Good luck with your application.